# Bind data only if all options is selected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this code, and i want, only if both options is selected, then return result into another variable.
I have this code:

```
var vars = [];
if (vars.length == 0) {
  if (this.selectedOption !== undefined) {
    vars.push({
      'option': this.selectedOption
    })
  }
  if (this.selectedOption2 !== undefined) {
    vars.push({
      'option': this.selectedOption2
    })
  }
}

if (this.selectedOption !== undefined && this.selectedOption2 !== undefined) {
  this.selectedVars = vars;
}
```

For now, if user select only one option, on console, im getting *"undefined"*. And i have an error when another function check for this both options.
So its possible in some way, then variable "**selectedVars**" wait before user select both options?
Sorry for my language and thx in advance!

Comment: `Is it possible to wait before the user selects both options`, definitely, how long do you want to wait? Are you talking about a timeout, or a button to validate?

Comment: wait, until user select both option, not only one! I think it need to validate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to trigger the code when both options are selected, you can do something like:

```
checkIfBothSelected() {
    if (this.selectedOption && this.selectedOption2) {
        this.selectedVars = [
                {option : this.selectedOption},
                {option : this.selectedOption2}
        ]
    } else {
        console.log("Both checkboxes are not selected.")    
    }
}
```

And on your checkboxes or options or whatever :

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" (click)="checkIfBothSelected()"/>
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption2" (click)="checkIfBothSelected()"/>
```

Comment: Is not working, becose, on other place, i have only one option to select, and this functions give me error, becose, selectOption2 is undefined... There is a way to insert on [(ngModel)] a default option, like a placeholder?

Comment: If you have only one option to select elsewhere, then don't use `checkIfBothSelected`, use another function.